# Opencv write text on image crashing No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(

Tags: image, opencv, android

Just i am write text on drawable image using opencv.But i am getting below error.I tried all SO answers but non of this worked.

Error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(int, int, int) (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat and Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__III)
>           at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {


    ImageView img;
    Mat mat;

    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                    Log.i("TAG", "OpenCV loaded Successfully");
                    mat=new Mat();
                    //mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                }
                break;
                default: {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        img = findViewById(R.id.img);
        mat = readImageFromResources();
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(mat.cols(), mat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(mat, bm);
        img.setImageBitmap(bm);

    }

    private Mat readImageFromResources() {
        Mat img = null;
        try {
            img = Utils.loadResource(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(img, img, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGRA);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log.e(TAG,Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
        return img;
    }


    public void m1() throws IOException {

        Mat mat = Utils.loadResource(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);//( image2mat( image ) );

        String text = "Funny text inside the box";
        int fontFace = FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX;
        double fontScale = 2;
        int thickness = 3;
        Point point = new Point(10, 130);
        //mat.        putText( mat, text, textOrg, fontFace, fontScale, Scalar::all( 255 ), thickness, 8 );


        //Imgproc.putText(mat, "Original Image",              new Point(mat.cols() / 4, mat.rows() / 2),                Core.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));

        Imgproc.putText(mat, "Video Mode", new Point(10, 50), 3, 1, new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 2);
        Bitmap resultbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mat.cols(), mat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(mat, resultbitmap);
        ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setImageBitmap(resultbitmap);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {


        try {
            m1();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {

    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        return null;
    }



    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d("OpenCV", "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
        } else {
            Log.d("OpenCV", "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of Utils.matToBitmap

Comment: that is predefined method in Opencv .

Comment: Here onResume is must be override method.

Comment: Good observation but actually in my code also it is overiding method but here edited text

Comment: I am just adding text to image not using opencvcamere so i think even these are not required But i need to add any method to add opencv in my first activity like                                           OpenCVLoader.initDebug()

Comment: try to add this line OpenCVLoader.initDebug(); in onCreate.